# Error: Class 'Bolt\CronEvents' not found

Tags: bolt-cms

Trying to use the cron scheduler with the following code (taken from the docs):

```
use Bolt\CronEvents;

class Extension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->app['dispatcher']->addListener(CronEvents::CRON_HOURLY, array($this, 'myJobCallbackMethod'));
    }
}
```

But I get the above error. Has the namespace changed since the docs were produced or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is indeed different:

```
use Bolt\Events\CronEvent;
use Bolt\Events\CronEvents;
```

Comment: The events were all moved during the 2.0 development cycle and those docs apparently were not updated.